# In which case a commit of a merged PR might not exist in the repo?

Tags: git, github

I am doing GitHub based mining operation and found an interesting case. [This URL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/26658/commits/c8e351d47b11d9f87867c254fec8070811396b5d) belongs to a merged PR of `spring-projects/spring-framework` repo. However, the page says

> This commit does not belong to any branch on this repository

I am interested to know under which circumstances *a commit of a merged PR* might not be present in the repository?

Comment: That PR was made from a _fork_, so the commit exists in _that_ repo. The equivalent in the target repo is https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/79b571038633721a804ffab8ddce6284790af8b6.

Comment: if you do a squash and merge, all commits will be combined into a single commit and will be added to base branch so they original commit won't be identical to the merged commit of the base branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have got answers from @jonrsharpe and @anand-vidvat, I don't want this question to be unanswered state. So, here is the answer based on their comment.

In GitHub, a merge can happen in two forms - 1) add all commits from the source branch to the target branch, or 2) squash all commits from the source branch into a new commit and only add that new commit to the target branch.

In the former style, all commits from all PRs can be found in the master/main branch. However, in the latter approach, the master/main branch will contain only the squash commit. Therefore, I could not find the *commit of a merged PR*  in the repository.